# Try and Catch with JOption Does not work as expected

Tags: java, loops, exception

```
    int i=0;
    int c=0;
    int a=0;
    int b=0;
    String stringy;
    String input;

    do { //loop for value a
        try // try-catch to prevent program from crashing
        {
            stringy= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type a value for a or press q to quit:");                       
            if (stringy.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) System.exit(0); 
            a = Integer.parseInt(stringy);
            i++;               
         } catch (Exception e) {
               stringy= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Error. Try Again! ");                 
         }  // end catch     
    } while(i==0); // end loop
```

the output produces a jOption input dialog box `("type a value...")` and when i enter in a string or something that the system does not expect, it goes to the `"catch"`and pops out `"error try again!"` However, when i enter in anything into that, even if it is a number, it goes back to the ("type a value...") dialog box. I want it to read the input in the error box instead of jumping back to the first dialog box. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Exactly what type of exception is being thrown? `Exception` catches them all, and I think the only one that you need to catch is `NumberFormatException`, I may be mistaken though

Comment: If you type in a number, i++ and then you should leave the loop. Just as you assumed. If it still repeats, maybe the entire code is repeated. Sherlock Holmes would express it a bit stronger.

Comment: I recommend you to format your code and to pay attention to the outcommented left bracket after the `do` keyword because _theoretically_ your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

You should take base input out of cycle, if you want to use input from `catch()`.
And use `break;` clause unstead of `while(i==0)` and `i++`;

```
       stringy= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type a value for a or press q to quit: ");
       while(true)
       {
           if (stringy.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) System.exit(0);
           try {
               a = Integer.parseInt(stringy);
               break;
           } catch (Exception e) {
              stringy= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Error. Try Again! ");
           }             
       }
       JoptionPane.showMessageDialog("Input accepted!");
```

And write your code in correct format please, you have commented '{' at the start of cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously have to check the input of the second dialog too, similar to the following:

```
stringy = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Error. Try Again! ");

if (stringy.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a String for output.

```
    String input;
    String output = "Type a value for a or press q to quit: "

    do  //loop for value a        {
        try // try-catch to prevent program from crashing
        {
            stringy= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(output);                       
                            if (stringy.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))          
            {
              System.exit(0);
            }             
            a= Integer.parseInt(stringy);
            i++;               
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
               output= "Error. Try Again! ";                 

         }
```